# WPF Blank Solution with multiple projects sharing same MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm having a Blank solution with multiple projects. I want the Wpfloginwindow to be linked with the other WPF projects (WpfMembers). What I mean is when I click on the connect button in the MainWindow.xaml of the Wpfloginwindow, I want the Mainwindow.xaml of WpfMembers to be shown. How can I do that? I only know how to do that when I'm having multiple windows in one project. But here is different I want to call the WPF window of another project but in the same solution (SlnProject).

[image]

Comment: WPF Window (like Form) is a regular class.
Without any problem, you can use any exe assembly (WPF, Forms, Console) as a class library.
Specify in the project in which you want to use, a reference to the project that contains the classes you need, and call these classes as classes of any assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An WPF window is a normal class that inherith from Window class. You can just call your member window from your login window, referencing the namespace from your member window:

Main window Login XAML:

```
   <Button Click="Button_Click">Connect</Button>
```

code behind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindowMember = new WpfMembers.MainWindow();
        mainWindowMember.Show();
    }
```

This is the simplest way to implement it. To improve your project architeture and decouple your business logical from UI, maybe you want to implement MVVM pattern:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem.